# How to prevent an Angular 2 pages from sliding to sides on dragging content, or scrolling?

Tags: angular, user-interface, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css, ng2-semantic-ui

Got an Angular 2 app.

When I scroll the page, the page behaves like I try to swipe a little it to the sides, and a horizontal rubber band effect is happening. An effect that seems like I'm trying to swipe the page to the sides.

This problem getting worse when I really swiping an element, like a carousel. Swiping the carousel to the sides, dragging the page together with the carousel.

How can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Really need more context to understand why this is happening, but a quickfix solution would be to make things you don't want to move unselectable: 
.unselectable {
 -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none
}
Just add that class to anything moving that shouldn't (may not work for ionic or similar mobile-app environments).'

Comment: Thanks man! Problem was totally different. It was caused by semantic-ui framework. I'll write all down in the answer to this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was actually different. It caused by the implementation of `semantic-ui` grid system.

It got negative margins, `margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px` and on mobile its making the screen to move horizontally on dragging.

I solved it by placing `overflow:hidden` over the main container. Simple as that.